# jQuery onclick not working in loaded class

Tags: jquery

I have simple script where I toggle div.

```
<div id='csupport'></div>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $( "#csupport" ).load( "csupport.php .email-item" ); 
    $( ".writee, .reply" ).click(function() {
     $(".format").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that the toggle function doesn't work for .reply class. The reply class is pulled from csupport.php. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: But it does work for `.writee`? Are you getting any console errors? F12 in Firefox or Chrome -> `Console` Tab.

Comment: .writee works because is in the same file but .reply is pulled from external file

Comment: can you share the html too? or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Try binding it to an `.on` function, like so: `$('.reply').on("click", function(e){ ... });` See thecodeparadox's answer!

Comment: @TimLewis, didn't work. And no, it doesn't have errors..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your elements are added to the page dynamically, you should use JQuery .ON() or .OFF() for binding events for dynamic things like this:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".reply", function() {
  $(".format").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As you're loading content via `.load()`, that's why `.reply` and `.writee` elements are appending to `#csupport` after page load, which makes them dynamic elements. So, you need event delegation (aka, live event binding).
Try this:

```
$( "body" ).on("click", ".reply", function() {
   $(".format").toggle();
});
```

Comment: @Grasper Better not to bind `body`, instead, bind to any closest Static Parent element that holds all those dynamic elements and it's good practice.